Error creating Razorpay order: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
const razorpay = new Razorpay({
    key_id: process.env.RAZORPAY_KEY_ID,
    key_secret: process.env.RAZORPAY_KEY_SECRET,
  });
  
  router.post('/createOrder', checkForAuthenticationToken, async (req, res) => {
    const { amount } = req.body;
  
    const options = {
      amount: amount * 100, // amount in the smallest currency unit (paise for INR)
      currency: 'INR',
      payment_capture: 1, // Auto-capture
    };
  
    try {
      console.log('Creating Razorpay order with options:', options);
      const order = await razorpay.orders.create(options);
      console.log('Razorpay order response:', order);
  
      if (order && order.id && order.currency && order.amount) {
        res.json({
          id: order.id,
          currency: order.currency,
          amount: order.amount,
        });
      } else {
        throw new Error('Invalid response from Razorpay');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating Razorpay order:', error);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
  });

I am trying to post this razorpay api but getting this 'Error creating Razorpay order: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined' , though i did not used status anywhere before and if had also tried by removing res.status(500) from res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error'); but still the same error.

Hi, Is this issue still persisting ?
